# CSS - Getting a div to display as much text as it can without going crazy

Tags: css

I've been working on creating a Spell check dialog for the tinyMCE editor using jQuery's dialog control. My reason for doing this is because our users have touch screens and the default method of click-word/click-replacement is too cumbersome.

I've finally got the spellcheck dialog to the point of everything works.

However, the div where I display the text can go nuts in 2 different ways if provoked.

For example, here is the dialog as I want it to work. Seen "working" here in ie7. http://jsfiddle.net/PMX8r/2/
[image: ie7]

Viewed in ie8 (or any newer browser) it is a much different matter.
[image: ie8]

The other issue is if the user enters a ridiculously long word my buttons get pushed away! Seen here in ie7.  http://jsfiddle.net/PMX8r/3/
[image]

What style properties should I be looking at get this div under control?

**Edit:**
Sweet, it looks like `overflow: hidden` solves the 2nd issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons aren't pushed aside for me, but the first issue, where text overflows the div, can be fixed by

```
.SpellCheckDiv {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Assuming there's some other way to scroll, otherwise use `overflow: scroll;`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
overflow: scroll
```

or

```
overflow: hidden
```

to the style tag of your container-textarea.

This will add scrollbars (1st case) or hide the overflowing text.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this behavior is your div is 100px in height and your content is exceeding the limit of 100px
 use `overflow:auto;` in your `.SpellCheckDiv` class.

```
.SpellCheckDiv
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 318px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:auto;
        }
```

overflow:hidden; - if you dont need scrollbars
you can use `overflow-x:{scroll|auto|hidden}` and `overflow-y:{scroll|auto|hidden}` to even controll your vertical and horizontal scrollbars too.(CSS 3)
You can test the result of different overflow behavior here
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_overflow-xy

Answer (score 1):

The `overflow` property should help you. With respect to your code:

```
.SpellCheckDiv
    {
        height: 100px;
        width: 318px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

It says when there is a overflow of text (i.e. it doesn't fit in the current window size), it should automatically scroll.

This is the [modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9zwQ/) code.